# how can i change selected option of dropdown depend of other select option?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the selected option depending on the other and reverse. but when i do that multiple times, the dropdown block, can i have some help to improve it if possible.

```js
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
    $select2 = $( '#select2' );


$select1.on( 'change', function() {
  var a = $(this).val();
  $( "#select2 option[value='"+a+"']" ).attr("selected", "selected");
});


$select2.on( 'change', function() {
  var a = $(this).val();
  $( "#select1 option[value='"+a+"']" ).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="1">Banana</option>
  <option value="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="3">Hawk</option>
  <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value to the select field not the option.

```js
const $select = $('.select');

$select.on( 'change', function() {
  const that = $(this);
  const a = that.val();
  $select.not(that).val(a);
  
  // if you want to get the text from the selected option you can do as follow:
  $select.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1" class="select">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" class="select">
  <option value="1">Banana</option>
  <option value="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="3">Hawk</option>
  <option value="4">BMW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note that you also have an open option tag for BWM, should be ```</option>```.

Comment: thank you very much for ur help...